# Yii - How to yiic.php migrate up domain.com

Tags: yii, migration

In yiic.php I include config: domian.config and futher crate yii app with main.config in which i try to use variables such as `$db_serv`, `$db_user` and so on. But these variables are undefined, although domian.config contains all of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure your domain.config is executed before you load main.config?

```
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/config/main.php';
```

this line in index.php on a yii project only defined a path. It dosn't execute the config in a first time.

Hope this helps